# Unity: How to pause execution until function terminates, so as to skip no frames

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, rendering, skip, pause

I am writing a game/program which every few seconds has to write a lot of data to the hard disk - this takes a few seconds to complete, and naturally causes the game to hang for that duration.

However, when the game resumes after the writes have completed, the game skips a few frames.

I need it that Unity will **skip** absolutely **no frames** what so ever. How can I force the Unity Engine to **stop executing until the writing has fully completed**, so that when it resumes, no frames have been skipped?

---

To provide some context, I am capturing a screenshot every frame, storing them as Texture2Ds in a queue. When the queue has more than 100 frames worth of Texture2Ds in it, I am writing the to the disk as PNGs, and clearing the queue.

I want to pause rendering/execution whilst the writing takes place so that the output (alone) is seamless.

Comment: If it causes the game to hang while that function is being completed then why don't use you another thread to execute that function so it doesn't stall the main thread? Multi threading.

Comment: Because that will allow the rendering to continue whilst the data is written to the disk. In my specific context, I want execution to completely pause whilst the PNGs are written, then resume as soon as it finishes. I don't want it to be executing/capturing frames whilst trying to write to the disk because the capturing is considerably faster than writing.

Comment: But why do you wait to write? Why don't you write as you save? One by one.

Comment: BTW moreover, what you are trying to do, is very, very complicated.  You're to going to get any simple canned answers Ben -- sorry for the bad news  :/

Answer (score 0):

You could set the timeScale to 0 so that Animation and FixedUpdate are not called.

As for the Update you would have to add some checks:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Manager.cleaningTexture == true){ return; }
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I have tried exactly this, but it hasn't quite worked. It still skips a frame or two. Not quite sure I understand how the If statement helps to prevent execution though?

Comment: You cannot stop Updates, this is simply not possible.  FixedUpdate can be skipped if timeScale is 0. The if statement prevents any code to run in update if the cleaning is happening. When you start the cleaning, you would set a flag. Then when the flag is true, the update skips. But it still has to be called, you cannot prevent that.

Comment: Thank you fafase, I realise this now. I have ended up writing the PNGs to disk in a separate thread. This seems to work quite well, despite being something which I thought was the wrong idea.

Comment: @BenHayward did you use a thread helper package (there's a few around, mostly called things like "Loom" and so on)...

Comment: @JoeBlow Ultimately I have got my answer from Unity answers - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1147247/how-to-pause-execution-until-function-terminates.html. I have created a coroutine which, despite my initial understanding, writes a single frame to the disk as soon as it is created. I have used Time.captureFramerate to force unity to only execute after the write has taken place. It works perfectly and no frames are skipped